# Error: object_detection.utils ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm following this tutorial (https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-your-own-object-detector-ad69dda69c85) to create my own object detector.

On the topic 'Generating TFRecords for training', whe i try run this code:

```
python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record
```

I got this error:

```
[...]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

My folder structure:

```
-generate_tfrecord.py
-images/
--test_labels.csv
--train_labels.csv
--test/
---*files*
--train/
---*files*
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

1. git clone

   https://github.com/tensorflow/models
2. Go to folder "research".
   Open terminal: *cd models-master/research*
3. (for 3.6python) *python3.6 setup.py build*

   (for 3.6python) *sudo python3.6 setup.py install*
4. You'll see : "*Finished processing dependencies for object-detection==0.1*"

### **Then do the follwing**

> Add Libraries to PYTHONPATH
>
> When running locally, the tensorflow/models/research/ and slim
>   directories should be appended to PYTHONPATH. This can be done by
>   running the following from tensorflow/models/research/:

#### From tensorflow/models/research/

> *export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim*

[Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2543)
[Source2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md)